# Grails 2.5.11 / Postgresql 10, Upload Image and Display in GSP

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy, gsp

Hi I am new to Grails and PostgreSQL. I am trying to make a form that stores  user's data and I want to be able to upload multiple photos.

service:

```
Cars carInstance = new Cars() 
carInstance.carimg = params.carimg.getBytes()
```

gsp:

```
<input type="file" id="carimg" name="carimg" multiple />
```

and I call `saveCar` action in controller that save all the data user will input.

And I want to display the data with the image in a `showCar` gsp this way :

```
 <img src="${createLink(controller: 'garage', action: 'getImage', params: ['id': Cars.id])}"/>
```

The `getImage` action which gets the image and passes it to on to gsp is this :

```
 def getImage(){
   def item = Cars.get(params.id.toLong())
   byte[] imageInByte=item.carimg
   response.contentType = 'image/png'
   response.outputStream << imageInByte
   response.outputStream.flush() }
```

In the gsp it appears as a blank border with an image in left corner that means image not found probably.
If I convert binary data to string it displays the correct photo name. 
Any suggestions? The problem is in the way I store the image or the way I try to display a binary data to image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `Cars.id` in your case? Maybe it is an array of cars and you need to iterate over it?

```
<g:each in="${Cars.list()}" var="car">
 <img src="${createLink(controller: 'garage', action: 'getImage', params: ['id': car.id])}"/>
</g:each>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Based on your responses I create a sample grails(2.5.6) project.

Domain:

```
class Car {
    String name
    byte[] photo

    static constraints = {
        photo maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
    }
}
```

In Controller I have 2 methods:

```
def show(Car carInstance) {
    respond carInstance
}

def showImage(int id) {
    def item = Car.get(id)

    byte[] imageInByte = item.photo

    response.contentType = 'image/png'
    response.outputStream << imageInByte
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

And gsp page with:

```
<g:fieldValue bean="${carInstance}" field="name"/>
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'Car', action: 'showImage', params: [id: carInstance.id])}"/>
```

And image was rendered successfully.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry, I miss what you try to do it with multiple images.

First of all you need to create additional Domain to store photos:

```
class CarPhoto {
    byte[] photo

    static belongsTo = [car: Car]

    static constraints = {
        photo maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
    }
}
```

and add this dependencies to Car Domain:

```
class Car {
    String name
    static hasMany = [photos: CarPhoto]

    static constraints = {}
}
```

After that you need to apply those changes to showImage action:

```
def showImage(long id, long photo_id) {
    def car = Car.get(id)
    def photo = CarPhoto.findByCarAndId(car, photo_id)

    byte[] imageInByte = photo.photo

    response.contentType = 'image/png'
    response.outputStream << imageInByte
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

And to the gsp page:

```
<g:each in="${carInstance.photos}" var="photo">
    <img src="${createLink(controller: 'Car', action: 'showImage', params: [id: carInstance.id, photo_id: photo.id])}"/>
</g:each>
```

Also you need to change your upload methods. You can find info [here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Multiple-file-upload-in-grails).

Comment: Class Cars is my domain , by car.id is the column id in my db

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention what my question was referenced to gsp page.

Comment: well it is a car garage gsp , so when i choose an id it must display all the data of a car like model catergory etc and some photos, car.id will pass the id of a specific car in order to display the photos of this car , but no photo is being displayed